# Generating Precipitation Diagrams with CompuTherm Pandat

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase, precipitation, alloy

I am trying to develop precipitation diagrams for an Ag-Cu-Sn alloy to figure out the kinetics involved using the CompuTherm Pandat Software (Demo Version).

The precipitation diagrams need the thermodynamics/mobility database and it further needs the kinetics database as well. The software I have installed comes only with Al-Ni Kinetic database.

Does anyone know how to get Pandat to generate diagrams for other alloys?
Their website is http://www.computherm.com/